# Bootstrap modal focus trap behaving differently on BS documentation page

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, accessibility

I'm using Bootstrap modal and it doesn't seem to trap focus inside the modal. However, when tested on Bootstrap webpage https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/ this is working as it should i.e. focus is trapped within modal.

I've just used the example code you can find on the BS website. Also, I've seen fixes for this issue but I'm just baffled why it's working in the BS webpage but not when I use the same code in my solution.

Any help is much appreciated.

JS Bin link to the code - https://jsbin.com/zadavagifo/edit?html,output

```js
$('#exampleModalCenter').modal();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I have encountered the exact same problem. I cannot find a clean way to do it so the option that worked for me was to force things to work as expected

```js
function handleTrapEvent(lastFocusableElement, firstFocusableElement) {
  return function eventHandler(event) {
    const isTabPressed = event.key === 'Tab' || event.keyCode === 9;

    if (!isTabPressed) {
      return;
    }

    if (event.shiftKey) {
      if (document.activeElement === firstFocusableElement) {
        lastFocusableElement.focus();
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    } else if (document.activeElement === lastFocusableElement) {
      firstFocusableElement.focus();
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  };
}

function addTrapHandler(modal) {
  const focusableElements = 'button, [href], input, select, textarea, [tabindex]:not([tabindex="-1"])';
  const firstFocusableElement = modal.querySelector(focusableElements);
  const focusableContent = modal.querySelectorAll(focusableElements);
  const lastFocusableElement = focusableContent[focusableContent.length - 1];

  document.addEventListener('keydown', handleTrapEvent(lastFocusableElement, firstFocusableElement));
}

function initTrap(modals) {
  modals.forEach((modal) => {
    addTrapHandler(modal);
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
  initTrap(modals);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. The thing is if you look at the Bootstrap site's example, it works as it should but when you try and implement it, it somehow doesn't trap the focus, which is so weird.

Comment: @ConsoleLog I was expecting some missed paragraphs explaining what I do wrong in the documentation but couldn't find them. Also, I was trying to find any script that overrides the bootstrap library on their page (the same principle as this answer) but also didn't find anything. I guess it should be a good idea to rise a bug in BS repository

Comment: @ConsoleLog https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/36368

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot for for raising this!

Comment: They've closed the ticket saying the version on documentation is different to the one in JSBin. I updated the JS links to v4.6 but still the same behaviour. :O

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer as to why this is happens, but I was able to work around the bug by moving my modal HTML further up in the markup.  When my modal was just above the closing body tag I experienced the same issue. After moving it to a higher position the modal focus trap worked as expected. The issue is vaguely mentioned in the [modal documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/#how-it-works).

Modals use position: fixed, which can sometimes be a bit particular about its rendering. Whenever possible, place your modal HTML in a top-level position to avoid potential interference from other elements. You’ll likely run into issues when nesting a .modal within another fixed element.